# Django-Compressor won't work in offline mode with custom S3 domain

Tags: django, cdn, boto, django-storage, django-compressor

I get the following error whenever a custom domain for the S3 endpoint is used.

```
#  WORKS 
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'example.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/{}'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
#  DOES NOT WORK ⁉️ 
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'cdn.example.com/{}'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
```

`CommandError: An error occurred during rendering /home/<user>/<app>/templates/public/index.html: 'https://cdn.example.com/storage/static/node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css' isn't accessible via COMPRESS_URL ('https://example.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/storage/static/') and can't be compressed`

If I go to either url the file is accessible, hence its likely that the CDN is ok, URLs are correctly defined, CORS are fine too.
Also without `django-compressor` subdomain delivery had been working fine, leading me to believe the issue is not with `django-storages`

I've been trying for several hours and ultimately had to do a temporary fix by setting the `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` to be the same as the `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL`. However this is not ideal.

Please see the implementation below.

**/requirements.txt**

```
Django==3.1.4
...
boto3~=1.16.46
botocore~=1.19.46
s3transfer~=0.3.3
...
django-storages~=1.11.1
django-compressor~=2.4
```

**/config/settings.py**

```
...
# ==========================================================
#  DJANGO-STORAGES
# ==========================================================
if LOCALHOST_MODE:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), ]
else:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'storage'
    AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://example.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com'
   
    #  WORKS ⚠️ 
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'example.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/{}'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
    #  DOES NOT WORK ⁉️ 
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'cdn.example.com/{}'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)  

    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
        'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
    }
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), )
    STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_LOCATION)
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storage_backends.CachedS3Boto3Storage'

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
    MEDIA_URL = '{}/{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, 'media')
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storage_backends.MediaStorage'

# ==========================================================
# DJANGO-COMPRESSOR
# ==========================================================
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
STATIC_DEPS = True
COMPRESS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

COMPRESS_FILTERS = {
    'css': ['compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter', 'compressor.filters.cssmin.rCSSMinFilter'],
    'js': ['compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter']
}

if LOCALHOST_MODE:
    COMPRESS_OFFLINE = False
else:
    COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
    COMPRESS_STORAGE = STATICFILES_STORAGE
    COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
]
...
```

**/storage_backends.py**

```
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

from config import settings


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    location = 'media'


class CachedS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3Boto3Storage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        super(CachedS3Boto3Storage, self).save(name, self.local_storage._open(name))
        return name
```

Comment: Supposed `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` to be something like `example.com` rather than `example.com/some/path` ?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-object-storage-with-django

See code sample just above 'step 6' header near the bottom of the page

Comment: I couldn't see any usage of `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`, but the `django-storage` doc doesn't have a similar example which has a *path* in its `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` variable

Comment: Yeah `django-storage` only has the example for the base domain https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#cloudfront, but without `django-compressor` it was working fine as `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'cdn.example.com/{}'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to debug this error:

Looking at where the error is raised (in [`django-compressor.compressor.base`](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/develop/compressor/base.py#L89)) we find the following:

```
    def get_basename(self, url):
        try:
            base_url = self.storage.base_url
        except AttributeError:
            base_url = settings.COMPRESS_URL

        base_url = str(base_url)
        if not url.startswith(base_url):
            raise UncompressableFileError(
                "'%s' isn't accessible via "
                "COMPRESS_URL ('%s') and can't be "
                "compressed" % (url, base_url)
       )
```

Looking at your settings:

- your `COMPRESS_URL` is set equal to `STATIC_URL`,
- which in turn is equal to `'{}/{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_LOCATION)`.
- This is `https://example.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/storage/static/`
- But the url being passed in is `https://cdn.example.com/storage/static/...`

This is the route of the problem.

#### So what's happening??

- `COMPRESS_URL` controls the URL that linked files will be read from and compressed files will be written to.
- When you have a CSS or JS file with a `link`, `rel` or `src` attribute somewhere, `django-compressor` calls `get_basename`.
- `get_basename` takes full path to a static file (eg. "/static/css/style.css") and
  returns path with storage's base url removed (eg. "css/style.css").
- Since the base path of some `link`, `rel` or `src` attribute doesn't begin with `COMPRESS_URL` (which it is expecting to be the base url) it can't remove it and so raises an error.

#### How to solve this

It's difficult to know exactly what is going wrong without seeing the whole project, however the below might help:

1. If you updated your `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` to match your `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`. This would in turn update your `STATIC_URL` (which I suspect is affecting the filenames in your files), and will also update your `COMPRESS_URL`. I think this might fix it.
2. Alternatively, just update `COMPRESS_URL` to use the correct url (although I think this needs to match `STATIC_URL` with your current setup).
3. If any (`link`, `rel` or `src`) urls in files that are being compressed are hard-coded they need to be updated to match your `COMPRESS_URL`.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the detailed explanation. I haven't tested it yet, but awarding due to the thorough explanation. Will update at some point with results, and mark as answered if that was the case. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Django Compressor has to be configured for remote storage. Section 2.5.1 of the [Django Compressor Documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-compressor/downloads/pdf/stable/) covers S3 and explains that you need to set

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
COMPRESS_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/'
```

and

```
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

in settings.py. Before I could get my app working, I still had to debug further such that I had to run collectstatic locally so that my_project/static matched my S3 storage. Then, I had to set

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = ''
```

The latter two bugs may be unrelated issues, but I thought I should mention them.